# Translating Zip, OrderedDict and DataFrame from Python to Typescript

Tags: python, pandas, typescript

I have the following code in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import collections
import copy

weekdays = { 1 : 'Null', 2 : 'Null', 3 : 'Null', 4 : 'Null', 5 : 'Null', 6 : 'Null', 7 : 'Null'}
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

days_in_month_in_year = {'2017' : [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 30, 30, 31], '2018' : [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31], '2019' : [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31],'2020' : [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31] }
days_in_month_in_year = pd.DataFrame(days_in_month_in_year, index=months)


startday = 7
month = 0
dict_of_months = collections.OrderedDict()

for index, row in days_in_month_in_year.iterrows():
    month_name = months[month]
    print (month_name)
    days_in_month = (row['2019'])


    month_df = pd.DataFrame({}, columns=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

    error_flag = 0
    for i, key in enumerate(weekdays, 1):
        if startday < 1 or startday > 7:
            error_flag = 1
            break
        elif i < startday:
            weekdays[key] = "Null"
            month_df.set_value(0, i, "Null")
        else:
            j = (i - startday) + 1
            weekdays[key] = j
            month_df.set_value(0, i, j)

    for key, j in zip(weekdays.keys(), range(j, days_in_month)):
        month_df.set_value(1, key, j + 1)

    for key, j in zip(weekdays.keys(), range(j + 1, days_in_month)):
        month_df.set_value(2, key, j + 1)

    for key, j in zip(weekdays.keys(), range(j + 1, days_in_month)):
        month_df.set_value(3, key, j + 1)

    for key, j in zip(weekdays.keys(), range(j + 1, days_in_month)):
        month_df.set_value(4, key, j + 1)

    for key, j in zip(weekdays.keys(), range(j + 1, days_in_month)):
        month_df.set_value(5, key, j + 1)

    month_df = month_df.fillna("Null")

    if len(month_df.index) < 6:
        null_row = pd.Series(['Null', 'Null', 'Null', 'Null', 'Null', 'Null', 'Null'], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
        month_df = month_df.append([null_row], ignore_index=True)

    startday = startday + ( days_in_month % 7 )
    if startday > 7:
        startday = startday - 7

    print (month_df)
    print (startday)
    month = month + 1

    dict_of_months[month_name] = month_df

print (dict_of_months)
```

I need to translate this to Typescript. I don't want people to do this for me in its entirety, but I thought it best to include my whole Python code for completeness.

So what are the best ways to reproduce the behaviour of an OrderedDict in Typescript??

How about if I want to reproduce the behaviour of zip?

What about dataframes? What structure should I use?

Here is my ts so far. It is very thin coz I am stumped where to start - heroes creates an array of html objects in the html file, and will be the array I eventually output to:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-events',
  templateUrl: './events.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./events.component.css']
})
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {

weekdays: any [];
monthslist: any [];
startday: number;
month: number;
heroes: any [];




  ngOnInit() {
    this.heroes = [
  { name: '' },
  { name: '' },
  { name: '' },
  { name: '' },
  { name: '' },
  { name: '' },
  { name: '' },
  { name: '' },
  { name: '' }
];
    this.weekdays = ['Null', 'Null', 'Null', 'Null', 'Null', 'Null', 'Null'];
    this.monthslist = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    this.startday = 7;
    this.month = 0;
  }

}
```

Comment: You should also add the base structure code of your typescript so far, it will help a lot too, I think. I like more the question if you would

Comment: No worries will do.